# How do I save custom data to a local database from FCM if the application is closed?

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

#### If the application running

We can receive FCM notification and can get data from it and save it in the database.

**If the application is killed**

The OS receives FCM and shows a notification. How can we save data in this particular case to the database?

Here `data` means `custom data` that comes in the from OS `key, value` pairs.